# Change Caret color of Entry in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, colors, xamarin.forms, caret

I want to change the caret colour of Text Entry in Xamarin.Forms. Is there anyway with that I can assign the same colour in all 3 platforms? Does Xamarin provide any control for this?

Thank You.

Comment: you most definitely should implement that specifically for each platform, forms can't help you with that.

Comment: no, you have to use tint color in android and similar platform specific things. You can create a custom render for the same.